# Invalid host header Nodejs cloudflare tunnels

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, tunnel

I am currently trying to run a nodejs app on my raspberry pi at home and create a tunnel to it using Cloudflare. I can confirm the tunnel works as I can connect to one of my other web servers just fine but I am having issues with this react app.
In case it is relevant in **package.json** I have a proxy that is pointed at an express app(`localhost:8080`) for api requests.
When I enter my domain for the node server I receive an `Invalid Host Header` error.

I have tried adding a **webpack.config.js** file which has allowed hosts set to all.

```
module.exports = {
    //...
    devServer: {
      allowedHosts: 'all',
    },
  };
```

This did not work

Answer (score 1):

I do this and its working:

cloudflared-windows-amd64.exe tunnel --url="localhost:8080" --http-host-header="localhost"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this by the dashboard, you have  to add the Http header

Extracted from the docs.

​​2. Connect an application
Follow these steps to connect an application through your tunnel. If you are looking to connect a network, skip to the Connect a network section.

In the Public Hostnames tab, choose a Domain and specify any subdomain or path information.

Specify a service, for example https://localhost:8000.

**Under Additional application settings, specify any parameters you would like to add to your tunnel configuration.**

Click this link and a small window will appear.

Check the http header and add `localhost`

Select Save tunnel.